# What are the correct symbols for kozumi?

Tags: kanji

While researching Japanese swords and sword construction, I have come across a term I can not find the correct kanji for. In Horimono (彫物) “engraving” on the blade or tang of a sword, the term 'kozumi' appears, with the description of 'claws'. I can only find English translations of this, with no kanji. Is this the correct term for this type of design pattern? if the term is correct, what is the appropriate kanji for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term for "claws" is 爪{つめ} tsume, not kozumi. It could be a mistake stemming from 小爪{こづめ} kozume. These two websites about swords ([www.touken-world.jp](https://www.touken-world.jp/tips/15368/), [kougetsudo.info](https://kougetsudo.info/horimono/)) both **only refer to 爪 in reference to Horimono**.
I also noticed that most of the hits for "kozumi claws" are variations of the same sentence. Seems like the Wikipedia sentence just got copied a bunch of times.

Comment: Incredibly helpful, and pointed me in the right direction.